# Create class with Injectable Parameters

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

Consider the following class:

```
class MongoDumpBuilder (recordingId: String, parquetService: ParquetService) {
...
}
```

I want to inject the `parquetService`, the problem is that I want to create `MongoDumpBuilder` as follows:

**NOTE:** I want to pass `recordingId.stringify` to the class

```
new MongoDumpBuilder(recordingId.stringify)
        .withPacificEvents(pacificEvents)
        .withAssets(assets)
        .withTransactions(transactions)
        .withReports(reports)
        .withExpenses(expenses)
        .build()
```

But this will work only with:

```
new MongoDumpBuilder(recordingId.stringify, parquetService)
```

If i will do `MongoDumpBuilder` with `Inject` i cannot create it

```
class MongoDumpBuilder @Inject()(recordingId: String, parquetService: ParquetService) {
???
}
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use naming in order to bind `recordingId`. Add this to your `Module`:

```
bind(classOf[String]).annotatedWith(Names.named("recordingId")).toInstance(recordingId.stringify)
```

Then define your class:

```
class MongoDumpBuilder @Inject()(@Named("recordingId") val recordingId: String, parquetService: ParquetService) {
...
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks but thats will not work for me, since there `mongoDumpBuilder` for  a lot of different `recordingId`s.

Comment: @ZviMints do you have a single `ParquetService`?

Comment: Its singleton but its not an object, its inject other dependenceis

Comment: @ZviMints Then I don't think you are doing a good usage of guice. Since you have a lot of `recordingId`s, it shouldn't be a class parameter, but a method. You should create one instance of `MongoDumpBuilder`, and pass inside the `recordingId`.

Comment: I got your advise, I changed the ParquetService to be object without dependences, Thanks as always :)